# Redis - max count of records with a key pattern that can expire

Tags: redis

Assume we are an online seller selling T-shirts. We have only 1 T-shirt left to sell. Incomplete orders are placed in redis and they auto-expire in 1 hour. We cannot sell more than the 1 remaining t-shirt, so we have to limit the number of pending order keys in redis to just 1. If the order is completed, the temporary order in redis will be deleted and the completed order written to the database for fulfillment.

If a customer comes, we have to check how much inventory is left (in our example, it is 1 t-shirt) and how many pending orders are already there in redis (before expiry), and if there is no available inventory to sell, we won't allow the t-shirt to be ordered if we don't have enough inventory (1 t-shirt in our hypothetical example).

Here is my stab at it (I am using redis for the first time - primarily because redis can auto-expire the pending keys which we don't need in any database).

1. Customer A visits. Check redis if pending orders exists -  scan "order:t_shirtid:1". None exist.
2. Start transaction - watch "order:t_shirtid:1", multi, setex "order:t_shirtid:1" 3600 1, exec
3. If customer B visits, we will see a pending order with key "order:t_shirtid:1" with a value of 1 and won't allow customer B to order
4. If after 1 hour, the key "order:t_shirtid:1" expires and hasn't been completed, customer B when he visits will see that there is nothing in redis with that key and can proceed to order

This strategy will fail sometimes because both customer A and customer B may go to different application servers, both discover there is nothing in redis for "order:t_shirtid:1", both will prepare to write to redis sequentially (i.e. the watch will have no effect because, first customer A goes, finishes everything, then customer B goes into redis and writes the same thing, but more importantly, both have finished the scan for "order:tshirt_id:1" one after another to know there are no pending orders in redis). So we've just enabled to customers to place the order even though only 1 T-shirt is left to sell.

So whats the right way to go about this use case. I am interested in learning what others have done. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using WATCH/MULTI/EXEC, the race condition can happen only when B's starts the transaction after A had finished (EXECed) it.

IMO, a better way to tackle this is to store the temporary orders in a sorted set. This will let you replace SCAN with an atomic Redis operation and include it in your transaction's flow, thus eliminating the race condition (as well as improve the performance). If you take this approach, however, you'll need to manually expire the ZSET's members (use the score to store the timestamp, periodically/upon access remove 1h-old members).

BTW, from your example it looks like there can't be more than a single temporary order for a given t_shirt ID.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. B has to start after A has exec'ed. The manual expiry is something I wanted to avoid because its yet another thing to keep track of within the application. Is there a Lua scriptable way of handling this better?

Comment: Sure - the logic is perfectly Lua-able. See this answer by (the one and only) Josiah Carlson for a similar approach (although it is in Python, it should be trivial to Lua-fy): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/-evvmnNWeaI/4GMSHgeixvEJ

Comment: Thanks again! One last question. How would we have to go about doing it periodically? Do we have to scan for every key of a particular pattern (like "order:tshirts:<tshirt_id>") and use ZREMRANGEBYSCORE after that? Also how do I prevent adding a second t-shirt to the "order:tshirts:<tshirt_id>" sorted set? Should we check its size in a transaction first? But inside a transaction would we be able to get the size first to make a determination on whether to add something new to the set? Sorry if the question seems naive - I am very new to redis

Comment: Personally, I prefer doing it after every touch to the key in question, so in your case do the ZREMRANGEBYSCORE whenever you add a new order to the item's sorted set. This, IMO, is preferable to periodically (e.g. cron) running a cleanup job. As for checking it in a transaction, sure - just WATCH the key in the beginning, read the relevant member and then start the MULTI block - if the key changes, the EXEC will fail. Re newness - no prob, we are all new at some stage ;)